# How to convert html & css to an image?

Tags: php, html, css, image, canvas

I'm developing an ecard-maker (I know it's awful, not my idea...). Is there any way to convert html and css of a specific dom-element to an image without using flash? I know there is image magick and the like, but it seems to be quite complicated to align and order the text properly.

Preferably I'm looking for a server-side solution, as posting an image from the client could take some time.

I found this: https://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/ but unfortunately I can only use php, ruby or client-side technologies.

Comment: @TJonS Not an option. I don't need the image for myself. It should be used inside of an email. As coherent email-templating is difficult and the client definetely wants an image, I don't have much of a choice.

Comment: Would you be able to run PhantomJS (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs) on the server? It's built on WebKit, so it should render html just as well as any browser. Here's an example of rendering as an image https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture.

Comment: And just as I'd written the above comment I saw that the answer below has been edited to include a PhantomJS/CasperJS example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Client Side solution

In Client Side, you can use something like library (that uses HTML 5): http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ =)

With it, you can use something like:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("element-id"), {
onrendered: function(canvas) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); // This should be image/png as browsers (only) support it (to biggest compatibilty)
  // Append image (yes, it is a DOM element!) to the DOM and etc here..
}
});
```

### Server Side solution

To get a server side solution, you can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) (that uses Webkit) or [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org/) (that uses Gecko).

A good library that is a wrapper to these two is [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/). Using CasperJS, a code that can be used is:

```
casper.start(casper.cli.args[0], function() {
    this.captureSelector(casper.cli.args[1], casper.cli.args[2]);
});

casper.run();
```

Save it as `screenshot.js` (just an example of name, you can choice a name too) and run it by using something like:

```
casperjs screenshot.js (URL) (image path) (selector)
```

From **any** language.

### A (possible better) alternative to Server Side

Other option is use [Selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/), but this is only valid if you **can** run Java in your server (and install browsers manually) (PhantomJS/SlimerJS/CasperJS, however, does not have these requeriments)

Use it only if you **need** to emulate a browser completely (maybe when using plugins...)

The best of Selenium is that you can use wrappers to connect to it (using Selenium Server), see the documentation to get the list: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/w/list

Comment: I've added some code of example to the answer to have a more complete answer to it.

Comment: +1 Very nice! Thank you. I'll wait a little more, to find out if there is a server side solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PHPImageWorkshop library (http://phpimageworkshop.com). Really simple and perfect for what you want to do.

It uses the system of "layers" in PHP.

Just initialize your first layer (the image) and create a second layer (your text).

It will create a final image with your first image + the text !

Comment: can this library convert HTML + CSS page to image ?

Answer (score 0):

### Server Side Solution

I've been using [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) + [HCTI API](https://htmlcsstoimage.com) to do this. You'll need an HCTI api key, but you can use a free account.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$html = "<div class='ping'>Pong ✅</div>";
$css = ".ping { padding: 20px; font-family: 'sans-serif'; }";

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('POST', 'https://hcti.io/v1/image', [
  'auth' => ['user_id', 'api_key'],
  'form_params' => ['html' => $html, 'css' => $css]
]);

echo $res->getBody();
```

Response returns a URL to the image:

`{"url":"https://hcti.io/v1/image/5803a3f0-abd3-4f56-9e6c-3823d7466ed6"}`